# Windows 10 enable login with work account

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, microsoft

within my organization an employee has received a laptop which had Windows 10 Home installed and set it up using his private microsoft account.

As we would like everyone to log into windows using their Microsoft Office Work account, we are currently trying to fix this accordingly.

First of all, we have purchased a Windows 10 Pro License and inserted the key to Windows using the command prompt. When checking at "Setttings>Security&Updates>Activation" it can be seen that Microsoft Windows 10 Pro is activated successfully.

Afterwards, we have switched the login to a "local account", so that we can remove the personal account of the employee, which worked successfully as well.

Now we are facing the following scenario: The computer has a local administrator account set up, as well as the work account attached in the section "work and school accounts".

However, if I want to switch from "local sign in" to "use microsoft account" sign-ins, Windows keeps rejecting the work account as it says "The E-Mail is not a Microsoft account" and prompts us to create a new one.....

How can we fix the situation, that the employee will be able to sign in with his Company Microsoft Account?

Thanks for any advise

Comment: Are you talking about the user logging in using an Active Directory domain account?

Comment: I would like the user to use the option "sign in via microsoft-account" but this account should not be a private one but a company microsoft account. Currently, if you try entering a company microsoft account into that option, it will not allow using it.

Comment: To add a Windows 10 workstation to a company's **MIcrosoft domain (a Active Directory service running on a Windows Server)** you must follow the following step-by-step in this Youtube video: ["How to join a Windows 10 PC to a Windows Active Directory domain"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Lsv4N1hGnM)

Comment: @Tom - Have you asked your IT administrator for assistant, you will need them, to resolve your issue